# Expand a data set using two columns

Tags: excel, excel-2013

In Excel, I have two columns of data that I wish to combine.

Current set of data:

```
+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 |
+---------+---------+
| a       | 1       |
| b       | 2       |
| c       | 3       |
| d       | 4       |
|         | 5       |
|         | 6       |
|         | 7       |
+---------+---------+
```

For each value in column1, I need to assign all of the values in column2 so it looks like this:

```
+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 |
+---------+---------+
| a       | 1       |
| a       | 2       |
| a       | 3       |
| a       | 4       |
| a       | 5       |
| a       | 6       |
| a       | 7       |
+---------+---------+
| b       | 1       |
| b       | 2       |
| b       | 3       |
| b       | 4       |
| b       | 5       |
| b       | 6       |
| b       | 7       |
+---------+---------+
| c       | 1       |
| c       | 2       |
| c       | 3       |
| c       | 4       |
| c       | 5       |
| c       | 6       |
| c       | 7       |
+---------+---------+
| d       | 1       |
| d       | 2       |
| d       | 3       |
| d       | 4       |
| d       | 5       |
| d       | 6       |
| d       | 7       |
+---------+---------+
```

How can I do this?
Do I need to find a macro/VB solution?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://www.contextures.com/excelmsquerycartesian.html

Comment: @guitarthrower - I'd tried many different searches, but I couldn't quite get the right combination of search terms to pull up when I needed.  Cartesian query was the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Since seems unlikely to receive any other answer:

in A1: `a`
in B1: `=MOD(ROW()-1,7)+1`
in A2: `=IF(MOD(ROW()-1,7)>0,CHAR(CODE(A1)),CHAR(CODE(A1)+1))`

Copy both formulae down to suit.